# Getting RoutingMissingException while migrating from ES 2.2.0 to ES 2.3.0

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am using `prepareDelete` query in a `BulkRequest` where I have a set of IDs which I have to delete.

I used:

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = searchClient.prepareBulk();
for id in ids {
    bulkRequest.add(searchClient.prepareDelete("indexName", "childType", id));
}
BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

This structure for deletion was working in ES 2.2.0 but in ES 2.3.0 I get `RoutingMissingException`.

If I print `bilkResponse.buildFailureMessage()` and I get

```
[0]: index [indexName], type [childType], id [215f3228a3c53970883ae0d3b22dae6f], message [[indexName] RoutingMissingException[routing is required for [indexName]/[childType]/[215f3228a3c53970883ae0d3b22dae6f]]]
```

I have not even changed the settings/mapping of the existing index.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue similar to the one answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965081/1871769)

Citing the answer for completion

> When you have a parent child relationship, you need to specify the
>   parent in the URL each time you try to access it a child, since
>   routing now depends on the parent.
>
> In your example, you'd want to try:
>
> curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/indexName/childType/215f3228a3c53970883ae0d3b22dae6f?parent=[parent_id]

This could also be helpful to you. [Delete child doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html#delete-parent)

Answer (score 0):

@rahulroc is right. I am adding a chronological list of references to the issues that introduced this feature:

1. [Don't broadcast deletes to all shards](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9123) (2014)
2. [Delete api: remove broadcast delete if routing is missing when required](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10136) (2015)
3. [Bulk api: fail deletes when routing is required but not specified](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/16675) (2016)

Maybe update 3 was the one that made the exception appear in `es-2.3.0`.
So you can just use `has_child` [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/has-child.html) for getting the parent from the child document id.